# Error when trying to retrieve from database

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have generated three classes from XSD schema:

```
public partial class PathDetailsMessage {
    private MessageHeader messageHeaderField;

    public MessageHeader MessageHeader {
        get {
            return this.messageHeaderField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageHeaderField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class MessageHeader {
    private Recipient recipientField;

    public Recipient Recipient {
        get {
            return this.recipientField;
        }
        set {
            this.recipientField = value;
        }
    }
}


public partial class Recipient {
    private string valueField;

    public string Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to put the value of id (which is a char in database) to medusa.MessageHeader.Recipient.Value, I get an error (see below):

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
  dr.Read();
  medusa.MessageHeader.Recipient.Value = Convert.ToString(dr["id"]);
  dr.Close();
}
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> PathDetailsMessage.MessageHeader.get returned null.
> ```

I use the following SQL string:

```
string sqlString = "SELECT id FROM view_otf WHERE id LIKE '%079%'";
```

id column is CHAR in database.

I can't figure out a solution for this issue.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

**LE**: Those 3 classes are in the same .cs file.

**LE2**: medusa is an object initialized from the PathDetailsMessage.cs file, class that was created from XSD schema

```
PathDetailsMessage medusa = new PathDetailsMessage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are missing the `medusa` initialization code, but you should do something like this:

```
medusa.MessageHeader = new MessageHeader {
    Recipient = new Recipient()
};
medusa.MessageHeader.Recipient.Value = Convert.ToString(dr["id"]);
```

That is because the initialization of a class like `PathDetailsMessage` will set no value to the `MessageHeader` property which will be null. The same applies to the `Recipient` property. So with the above initialization, you'll have some object to store the value.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the above initialization and it works!